# Is there any any way to find out why exactly the question ban occured, or is it just an automatic points based system?

Tags: support, post-ban

Is there any any way to find out  why exactly the question ban occured, or is it just an automatic points based system?

Comment: I'm not sure the exact formula is known. However, we do know it takes into account multiple past questions, including deleted (hidden) ones.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0: ([1](//stackoverflow.com/q/58981497) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/58976487) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/58965878) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/58776602) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/58742241))

Comment: @SamuelLiew Ty for the answer. Though I haven't found that info in the linked answer; there it says the system mechanics are secret to keep people from trying to circumvent it. - I must admit I didn't read all links to 100%, but while looking at your top answers in your profile, I found something interesting about the review queues: At least it tells me there are many people with high reputation score who have other views about what SO's review/valid questions guidelines mean than SO itself obviously. Sadly many highest voted questions nowadays wouldn't get through the SO's "demands".

Comment: The only "demand" is that askers ask a specific answerable question that has a right answer.

Answer (score 10):

No, the *exact* method isn't revealed, but it has a lot to do with poorly-received questions. Zero-scored questions aren't well-received, and questions which are deleted *still count*.

Comment: Does that mean that there's a limit to how many ignored Questions (no votes) a user can post too?

Comment: Yeah.  If one is posting a *lot* of questions which have a net score of zero, then...that's a reasonable indication that something fishy is going on.